# How to parse a date with milliseconds?

Tags: rust

I have a date in the following format: `"2014-03-10 11:20:34.3454"`. How can I parse this date?

The [chrono doc](https://lifthrasiir.github.io/rust-chrono/chrono/) mentions parsing year, month, ..., minutes and seconds. No milliseconds. Also when I look at [rust-datetime](https://github.com/ogham/rust-datetime/blob/master/src/format.rs) again - no milliseconds.

On the other hand, I can create a `DateTime` like this `UTC.ymd(2014, 11, 28).and_hms_milli(7, 8, 9, 10)`. So Rust knows milliseconds...

Comment: It appears you are out of luck :( A quick request to the authors might get it added ^^

Comment: Ok, what's the best way how to contact authors, please?

Comment: Open an issue on github, I would assume.

Comment: https://github.com/lifthrasiir/rust-chrono/issues/40

Answer (score 7):

```
extern crate time;

fn main() {
    match time::strptime("2014-03-10 11:20:34.3454",
                         "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f")
    {
        Ok(v) => println!("{}", time::strftime("%Y/%m/%d %H:%M:%S.%f",
                                               &v).unwrap()),
        Err(e) => println!("Error: {}", e),
    };
}
```

Output:

```
2014/03/10 11:20:34.345400000
```

`strptime()` and `strftime()` are quite helpful when using time values. Plus, they tend to work in most languages so learning it once pays well over time.

Comment: this is nice, you have to jump through hoops to get milliseconds in C++. I wish rust was 30 years old.

Comment: As an aside, `"%F %T"` is a strftime shortcut for `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"`. Also the description of `%D` is always worthy of a giggle. http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/strftime.3.html

Comment: You can use `"%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%3f"` to limit the number of digits parsed. `%3f` will parse milliseconds, `%6f` parses microseconds and `%9f` will parse nanoseconds. See https://docs.rs/chrono/latest/chrono/format/strftime

Answer (score 0):

you can try this:

```
use gostd_time as time;

fn main() {
    let t = time::Now();
    let date = t.Format(time::RFC3339Nano);

    println!("{}", t);
    println!("{}", date);
}
```

Output:

```
2021-11-08 07:25:26.920393 +0000 UTC m=+0.000011840
2021-11-08T07:25:26.920393Z
```